# Closing form from Sub

Tags: vb.net

I want to close the main form from a "Sub"; as I am using the sub from the "Exit" of the Menu too;
I wrote the code below, but I am having problem when user click "Cancel" in the YesNoCancel Dialog;
My code is below:

```
        If MekdamFirstLetters = "*" Then
        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("The File:  " & _
                    vbCrLf & _
                                            "      (" & File & ".txt) has been changed," & _
                    vbCrLf & _
                                            "                do you want to save it? ", _
        "Mekdam Message 701", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            '***********************
            ' THE ISSUE IS HERE;
            'Me.Cancel = True
            '***********************
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
            Application.Exit()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            SaveFileDialog()
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? It's not really clear. How is the sub called? Is it an event handler? If so, for which event?

Comment: When user close the Form; it will call the above Sub; if he/she clicks cancel in the YesNoCancel Dialog; the above Sub will still Exit; I want it to stay in the Form and not Exit.

Comment: Check the close reason in the FormClosing EventHandler

Comment: I could not find "FormClosingÈ EventHandler; do you mean in the properties window or in the code?

Comment: Provide the full method code.

Comment: What are you wanting to do if/when the user cancels the MessageBox? What Subroutine is this code in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my Comment your best bet would to put your code into the [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) EventHandler, this will give you the opportunity to cancel the close.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If MekdamFirstLetters = "*" Then

        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("The File:  " & _
                    vbCrLf & _
                                            "      (" &
                                            File & ".txt) has been changed," & _
                    vbCrLf & _
                                            "                do you want to save it? ", _
        "Mekdam Message 701", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            e.Cancel = True  'This will stop the form from closing
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
            'Application.Exit() 'no need to explicitly exit, you are already doing it this will lead to a loop
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            SaveFileDialog()
            'Application.Exit() 'Same here
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, Mark it is you, I did not recognize you until I saw your photo :-)    I can see that you moved the code to the Form1_FormClosing, but I want to have it in separate Sub, so that I can access it from another location (like from the Exit of the Menu; i.e. when used click Exit, the code in the Sub will be executed. in this case I cannot call the Form1_FormClosing from another location.

Comment: You do not need to call this from another location, it is run automatically when the form closes. Just use `Close` or `Me.Close` instead of the call to a separate subroutine and it will run.

Comment: Much appreciated Mark; It works :-) I learnt how to accept the answer and add ranking now in StackOverflow.